# UID mapping in NFS

Tags: linux, users, nfs

Can anyone let me know how can I map a UID 162 to UID 107.
Files in my nfs are getting created with ownership 162:162 but on my local machine the userid for that specific user is 107 so I need to map it.

`/etc/idmapd.conf`

```
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody
```

Can anyone let me know how to map it in `idmap.conf`.

Comment: It may be more sensible to synchronize the user accounts between the systems via LDAP or configuration management than to maintain a mapping table.

Answer (score 4):

nfs4 does not use uid numbers but usernames. You can add to your `/etc/idmapd.conf`

```
[Translation]
   Method=static
[Static]
   fred@remote = localfred
```

where `fred` is the username on the remote, and localfred is the local username.

Comment: Thank you, but the files are not getting created by username they are getting created by a uid 162 which on local machine is 107.

Comment: Not worked for me.

Comment: not worked for me either.